# Searching for files in my computer's filesystem named food using find . and grep together

Tags: macos

So I'm trying to run a search of my computer's entire filesystem for files named "food" using find . and grep together.  According to my homework instructions the search should take a while. I've tried

```
Enriques-MacBook-Pro:~ enriquequevedo$ find . | grep food
```

but it ran for only a couple of seconds and yielded no search results. Help with the proper command for this would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to use grep? find can find files by their name on its own. Have you searched for some examples online? Does your assignment not give you any?

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in your prompt indicates that your current directory is your home directory. By using the `.` as the first argument to `find`, you're telling `find` to start its search from the current directory, so your full command is going to find only files whose names contain the string "food" and that reside in or under your home directory.

To search your computer's entire file system, use `/` as the first argument to `find`. Alternatively, you could `cd /` first, then use `find .`.

As slhck wrote, there is no need to use `grep`. You can use the `find` option `-name \*food\*` instead. On the other hand, the purpose of the homework could be to learn to use pipelines.